# Steps to compile a bunch of C files using Mingw into DLL

Tags: c, windows, dll, compilation, mingw

I *desperately* try to compile a bunch of C files into DLL. I also have `Makefile.am`, `configure.ac`, `autogen.sh`. I have already installed Mingw and Cygwin (not sure its a good idea to have both). I have also set `PATH` to `Mingw\bin`.

What exactly to do, which of the make/config files are to start with? Looks like a simple task for who knows what to do.

Comment: maybe you should just try to do it manually before using makefiles. `gcc -fPIC -rdynamic -o mylib.dll foo.c bar.c`

Comment: ok, sounds like a good idea if nothing simple have appeared yet)

Comment: @rgipper actually, being able to just type "make" is orders of magnitude simpler, but frankly, `make` has quite a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: I made it your way using batch, so if you post it as the answer, I'll mark it. Though I have upvoted @lorenzo-donati coz he presented very similar concept that worked.

Comment: Ouh, I felt asleep, let Lorenzo have those points if his answer worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid Cygwin. MINGW should be enough.

Before trying to build your DLL make sure your MINGW installation works as expected (try a simple "hello world" program).

After you verified you can compile and link a simple C file into a working executable, you could try using a very simple approach using a Windows batch file.

Try to adapt the following to your needs. You should put it in the same directory where all your C files are placed and then run it. I assume that you can invoke `gcc` from the command line (i.e. GCC executable must be on your path).

```
@echo off
::
:: file  "build.cmd"
::
setlocal
set CWARNS=-pedantic -Wall -Wextra ^
  -Waggregate-return -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual ^
  -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdisabled-optimization ^
  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow ^
  -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wunreachable-code
set CFLAGS=-O2
set COMPILE=gcc -c %CFLAGS% %CWARNS%

%COMPILE% file1.c
%COMPILE% file2.c
%COMPILE% file3.c

gcc -shared file1.o file2.o file3.o -o mydllname.dll
```

It is not guaranteed to work, but if your project has no external dependencies and the `file*.o` (produced when compiling the sources) needn't be linked in a specific order, it should be enough.